# transfer all the databases in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

is there a more efficient method to transfer all the databases from phpmyadmin,rather than to create database copies and manually import them on other machines.

Earlier I tried to copy the entire folder and replace the older config.inc.php but I am unable to see all the databases

Comment: Do you have access to command-line mysql utilities?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of options which usually depends on your needs/db size/tables engine and so on:

1. mysqldump + rsync dump + restore (if you do not have a good connection between hosts)
2. mysqldump  | mysql -h H -u  -p
3. If you can't stand with big downtime you can setup replication between two hosts using `innodbbackup` utility

If you use MyISAM tables you can shutdown MySQL you copy related files to destination datadir. This option will not work for InnoDB tables.